# Expected number of objects of type A I will get if I take $K$ objects.

Tags: probability

Suppose I have:

- $x$ objects of type A.
- $y$ objects of type B.

Now I take $K$ objects randomly, taking each object with the same probability. What is the expected number of objects I will get of type A?

I can solve it using dynamic programming but its too costly for big values.

Comment: Google "Hypergeometric distribution" (no replacement) and "Binomial distribution" (with replacement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it we have a total of $x+y$ objects, and we take a sample of $K$ objects, *without replacement*. Then the number of Type A objects we get has *hypergeometric distribution*. If you like, you probably find everything you need about the hypergeometric distribution by going through parts of [this Wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution)

In particular, you will find that the expected number of Type A objects is $K\dfrac{x}{x+y}$.

**Remark:** The proof is quick, if one has some background in random variables. We can imagine that the objects are removed and examined one at a time. Let random variable $W_i$ be equal to $1$ if the $i$-th object chosen is of Type A, ane let $W_i=0$ otherwise. Then the number of Type A objects selected is equal to $W_1+W_2+\cdots +W_K$. By the linearity of expectation, we have 
$$E(W_1+W_2+\cdots +W_K)=E(W_1)+E(W_2)+\cdots +E(W_K)/$$
Each $W_i$ is $1$ with probability $\frac{x}{x+y}$, so has expectation $\frac{x}{x+y}$. It follows that the sum has expectation $K\frac{x}{x+y}$.

Answer (score 0):

This is hypergeometric distribution. If $K$ is the number of type $A$ items and $x+y=n$, use this:
$$
P(K=0)=\frac{\binom{y}{k}}{\binom{n}{k}}\\
P(K=1)=\frac{\binom{x}{1}\binom{y}{k-1}}{\binom{n}{k}}\\
\ldots\\
P(K=k)=\frac{\binom{x}{k}}{\binom{n}{k}}
$$
This assumes $k \leq x$.